# Trigonometry identities used to find x

Tags: trigonometry

I need help solving this. I know the trig equations, but I have trouble plugging them in. Solve $[0,2\pi]$: $\sin2x=\frac12\sin x$

Comment: Hint: $sin(2x)=sin(x+x)=...$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin 2x=\dfrac{1}{2}\sin x$$
$$2\sin x\cos x=\dfrac{1}{2}\sin x$$
$$4\sin x\cos x-\sin x=0$$
$$\sin x (1-4\cos x)=0$$

therefore the solutions in $[0,2\pi]$ are $0, \pi, 2\pi$ and $ \arccos {\Big(\dfrac{1}{4}\Big)}$, $2\pi-\arccos {\Big(\dfrac{1}{4}\Big)}$